# Using SED with 2 search criteria

Tags: shell, sed

I need to modify an existing script which uses SED to search and replace in a file.
My problem is that i need to use sed to do the same search and replace but only if 2 criteria is met.

I use find and sed like below :

```
find . -name 'search.do*' -exec sed -i "/href/\
s/href=\"[^\"]*sommerhus\/detail\.do[^\"]*unitId=\([^\"]*\)\"/href=\"sommerhus-\1.html\"/g" {} \;
```

but now i need to make sure that the replacement only takes place if the "href" AND another search criteria is met f.x "href" && "language" is present

I have tried with -e but without success.
Is it possible ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `/href.*language\|language.*href/` (possibly with some extra constraints, like a space before the second word in each match).

You could also nest the commands in blocks:

```
sed '/href/{ /language/s/<match>/<replace>/ }'
```

This is more extensible: adding a third pattern only requires adding in one pair of braces and the pattern, while the alternation solution above requires 6 patterns in total (one for each possible order).

---

Also, to save having to backslash the `/` inside the pattern, sed allows you to use any character as a separator, e.g. `@`:

```
find . -name 'search.do*' -exec sed -i "/href/\
s@href=\"[^\"]*sommerhus/detail\.do[^\"]*unitId=\([^\"]*\)\"@href=\"sommerhus-\1.html\"@g" {} ;'
```

(A small gain in this case, but nice to know for other situations when handling file paths or URLs etc.)

Comment: TIL about nesting searchpatterns in `sed` although using it since err, when I was young, thankyou @dbaupp.

Comment: +1: also note that some redundancy can be avoided: `sed '/language/{ \@href="[^"]*sommerhus/detail\.do[^"]*unitId=\([^"]*\)"@s//href="sommerhus-\1.html"/g }`

Comment: I used the simple solution you provided with href.*language. Should have thought of that myself, but thanks a lot.